# Enabling long file path in registry and gpedit.msc is not working

Tags: powershell, filesystems, filepath

I need to create folder with long file path more than 250 char using powershell cmd.

I did the following things,

1, In this registry path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem",
I had  changed the value for LongPathsEnabled as '1'

2,I have enabled long file path  in  "Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem >Enable Win32 long paths" (gpedit.msc)

But while creating a folder with  more than 250 char using power shell cmd , its throwing a error as below

"New-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: i've never done that ... but i wonder if you need to re-login to trigger the change? or perhaps reboot?

Comment: Usually changes in registry requires a restart to the explorer.exe process.
You can do this from the task manager.
And then from run command type "explorer.exe"

Comment: i  restarted the machine twice after  the registry changes . its not worked

Comment: Not sure, but I think you need to use `-LiteralPath` for long file names. Unfortunately, the `New-Item` cmdlet does not have that parameter, so maybe try create the new folder locally first and then use `Copy-Item -LiteralPath ..` ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `\\?\` prefix as in the following example:

```
$longPart = $( 65..86 | ForEach-Object {
    [string][char]$_ * 10
} ) -join '\'
$Path = "\\?\D:\PShell\DataFiles\$longPart"
$longPart.Length, $Path.Length -join ','
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path
```

> ```
> 241,265
>
>
>     Directory: \\?\D:\PShell\DataFiles\AAAAAAAAAA\BBBBBBBBBB\CCCCCCCCCC\DDDDDDD
>     DDD\EEEEEEEEEE\FFFFFFFFFF\GGGGGGGGGG\HHHHHHHHHH\IIIIIIIIII\JJJJJJJJJJ\KKKKK
>     KKKKK\LLLLLLLLLL\MMMMMMMMMM\NNNNNNNNNN\OOOOOOOOOO\PPPPPPPPPP\QQQQQQQQQQ\RRR
>     RRRRRRR\SSSSSSSSSS\TTTTTTTTTT\UUUUUUUUUU
>
>
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
> ----                -------------         ------ ----                          
> d-----       03.01.2020     22:58                VVVVVVVVVV
> ```

[About the `\\?\` prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces):

> For file I/O, the "`\\?\`" prefix to a path string tells the Windows
>   APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows
>   it straight to the file system.
>
> ...
>
> Because it turns off automatic expansion of the path string, the
>   "`\\?\`" prefix also allows the use of "`..`" and "`.`" in the path
>   names, which can be useful if you are attempting to perform operations
>   on a file with these otherwise reserved relative path specifiers as
>   part of the fully qualified path.

Note that you cannot use the "`\\?\`" prefix with a relative path.

Works with the following `LongPathsEnabled` in registry:

```
reg.exe query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -v long*
```

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
>     LongPathsEnabled    REG_SZ    1
> ```

Comment: If this is a UNC path, you'll need `\\?\UNC\server\share\filename.txt`

Comment: @Theo you are right. It's specified in the [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation) paragraph of the same document linked in my answer. However, I'm not sure whether long paths should be enabled then  for server, client or both? _I won't be in want of such a knowledge, I hope:)_

Comment: @Theo With this syntax you *can* access UNC paths prefixed with ```\\?\```, but then the path limitation seems to be active again. I will get path length errors on a network share with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\server\share'`.